# Why does my Iron Phoenix no longer spawn Golems?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I’ve built an [Iron Phoenix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxixJ5P_V7k) and I’m fairly sure everything is how it’s supposed to be. It spawned golems at the beginning, but it no longer does. I am on Xbox one.

I noticed a golem has spawned on top of the east structure. I think that is because some extra doors are still loaded, which pulls the village center slightly to the east, preventing any golems from spawning, except for this one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73163/discussion-on-question-by-carter-ray-iron-phoenix-troubleshoot-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all I have done is moved the 40 something villagers away from the farm one block. I did that a while ago and it still didn’t work because I had fiddled with other things. I put everything back to how tango says to make it, except the villagers. They are 1 block further away from the machine. I afked over night and got a double chest and a half of iron, so I would say it works now.

I accidentally left the area. So I manually put all the villagers back to their starting positions, unloaded the chunks for a few minutes, came back and started it up. It *seems* to be working still.